# How can I add an "Email This" button that will NOT use mailto:

Tags: php, html, email, forms, share

I want a button that does not just use a mailto: link. I want it to make either a popup, overlay or new window which has a simple form which allows anyone to email the link of the page they are on to another friend, with the subject and content pre-filled but editable. 
Something similar to how you can do it on google maps by clicking "Send"

I thought this would be simple to find and I would be amazed if no-one has made some sort of easy javascript plugin or something.

I would rather not use something like "addthis" or other similar sharing aggreator service.

I have looked around here and scoured google but cannot find anything. If I missed a topic or if there is a good tutorial it would be much appreciated!

Comment: There's no Javascript plugin for it because it requires server-side interaction. That said, I'm almost certain that the bundle (JS+server side code) can be found somewhere.

Comment: Are you wanting the FROM be your site's email or the user's email account?

Comment: I want the from: to be a visitor defined email address. it is going to be used for sharing lthe current page to friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is only possible with server side code. Your server will need to have access to a mail server so that it can compose and send on behalf of your user. This has most definitely been prebuilt, but you will need to let us know what server side language you are using before someone can point you to a solution. If you don't understand server side code then you will have to resign yourself to using a mailto: link or a third party service.

**UPDATE - Example**

In your HTML

```
<form action="http://mysite.com/sendemail.php" method="post" name="myform" >
    <input name="from" type="text" value="me@mysite.com" />
    <input name="to" type="text" value="me@mysite.com" />
    <input name="subject" type="text" value"Subject" />
    <input name="body" type="text" value="Hello World" />
</form>
```

In your PHP file

```
$from = $_POST['from'] ;
$to = $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'] ;
$body = $_POST['body'] ;
mail($to, $subject, $body, "From:" . $from);
```

Because the form is set to method POST you can access each form element by its name and the _POST variable. So $_POST['from'] get the form elements whose name = "from".

Comment: I have dabbled in php but am very much a novice. That said I think php is my best bet for server side code.

Comment: It is pretty straightforward. Here is a help document on w3 schools. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp. Basically you create a form on your html page. Submit it to a php page to process it. I added some pseudo-code to my answer so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery you can see the sharing plugins on offer here: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/share

One of them sounds like what you need ([Share Email](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/share-email)):

> A simple share this page via email
>   plugin that grabs the page title, url,
>   meta description and makes a mailto
>   link with Subject and Body pre-filled.

Comment: That looks pretty good, but what I am trying to avoid here is using a mailto link, the reason I want to avoid it is because I don't want the user's mail client to open up. Personally I never have a mailclient setup on my computer and just use gmail, I hate when I click a mailto link and have to wait for outlook to try and configure itself, I want to avoid this situation for users but still enable them to share a page to a friends email.